# Require controller, factory, service and directive files with Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, browserify

In my gulp-browserify setup I'm writing a new AngularJS application. Because I know it's gonna be a very big application I want my base structure as clean and clear as possible.

In my main entry javascript file for browserify I setup my main angular module and define the routes with ui-router in my app.config event.

Now I don't want a single `require()` statement for every single controller/factory/directive in my application.

I was hoping I could require all the files in a directory like this:

```
require('./dashboard/*.js');
require('./users/*.js');
require('./settings/*.js')
```

But apperantly you can't.

What would be the cleanest way to require all my app files in my app's main entry point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I found a module which did exactly what I wanted: [Bulkify](https://github.com/substack/bulkify)

**1) Install Bulkify with NPM**:

```
npm install bulkify
```

**2) Require Bulkify in your Browserify task:**

```
var bulkify      = require('bulkify');
```

**3) Just before your browserify.bundle() add the bulkify transform:**

```
var bundle = function() {
    return b.transform(bulkify)
        .bundle()
};
```

**4) In your javascript files use the bulk function:**

```
require('bulk-require')(__dirname, ['./*/*.js']);
```

This will require every javascript file in any of the curren file's subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to look at approach described in [article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/angularjs-browserify/)

Main idea of it put to each folder like `controller` or `service` their own `index.js`.
In this case in your `app.js` should be some kind of require:

```
var angular = require('angular');
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

// one require statement per sub directory instead of one per file
require('./service');
require('./controller');
```

and `index.js` in `controller` folder looks like

```
var app = require('angular').module('todoApp');

app.controller('EditTodoCtrl', require('./edit_todo'));
app.controller('FooterCtrl', require('./footer'));
app.controller('TodoCtrl', require('./todo'));
app.controller('TodoListCtrl', require('./todo_list'));
app.controller('ImprintCtrl', require('./imprint'));
```

and example of `controller` declaration - `todo.js`

```
module.exports = function($scope, TodoService) {
    // ...
};
```

For more details please look original [article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/angularjs-browserify/).

Comment: This would be managable but as the app is going to be so big I'm not using that folder structure. Instead I have folders for features of the app. More information [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure). And now really you are moving the require statements rather then getting rid of them

Comment: It doesn't matter what folder structure you are using, idea, as you mentioned, redistribution `require` to some specific sections. And if you add some new object you should update just connected to this section `index.js`. In other case, but I don't know is it compatible with browserify. You can try npm module - **[require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir)** or some kind of analog of it

Comment: My specific goal was to get rid of every require statement for my application files. In the end I found a module that did what I needed: bulkify. Thanks for your time though!